# Spherical Data?

Tags: clustering, ordinal-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am current using cluster analysis. Hierarchical clustering using the ward method appears to be the best method I have found. I read that this method is good for spherical data. I do not know what this is. I tried to look it up but could not find out exactly what spherical data is. I have ordinal data which I am guessing is not spherical data.

Comment: an example of spherical data are geographical data that data are on the surface of an sphere. a famous example is spherical regression http://www.jstor.org/stable/30042073?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: "I read" is fairly vague. Please provide references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think in three dimensions for clarity of exposition.

By "spherical" the cluster analysis references refer to a situation when you have several volley balls in the space: each cluster has a roughly round shape. This is an ideal situation, as real word clusters may look more like the balls used in  rugby/American football that are longer in some dimensions more than in other dimensions, and the longest axes may be oriented differently in space. (R `mclust` package is probably the best tool to deal with these.) Clusters may have other shapes, like bananas or snakes or donuts. For those complicated geometries, single linkage (that contracts or shrinks the space very severely) is probably one of the few methods that work.

If the clusters are approximately round and well isolated from one another, then pretty much every method will identify them.